# Only show modal box if the form fields are valid and filled in - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a two field form that once the user clicks submit a modal pops up and they have to accept some terms to complete the registration process. However my two field form has `required type="name"` assigned to the form fields so the form fields have to be valid to proceed. So at the moment when I click submit and the form is empty I get the form field pop ups saying required field and the modal at the same time, where as I need the modal popup coming only if the form fields are filled in. So far I have tried the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    $('.modal').addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="login-form" action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label>
    <input class="form-input" required type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="New Password" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="form-label" for="retype">Retype password</label>
    <input class="form-input" required type="password" name="retype" id="retype" placeholder="Repeat Password" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary sub-btn" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

.modal code

```
<div class="modal" id="modal-id">
   <a href="#close" class="modal-overlay" aria-label="Close"></a>
   <div class="modal-container">
      <div class="modal-header">
         <a class="text-primary text-uppercase text-bold text-small float-right close" href="#modals" aria-label="Close">Close<i
            class="icon icon-close icon-right"></i></a>
         <div class="modal-title">
            <!-- content here -->
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="content">
            <!-- content here -->
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your modal has an ID. Use it. When targeting specific elements use specific selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of bind your function to the button click, use the form submit event.
Like that:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#login-form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".modal").addClass("active");
    });
  });
```